# How to call cffunction on the cfm page from javascript?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cffunction

I was wondering if I can call `cffunction` on my cfm page? I have `onClick` button that should make a call to the `cffunction` that is on the same page. Also I have tried to put `cfcomponent` around my function but I was getting this error:

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 94 at column 1.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

&lt;
The CFML compiler was processing:
&lt; marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag.Did you mean LT or LTE?
```

So far I have this:

```
<cffunction name="getRecords" access="remote">
    <script>
        alert('test');
    </script>
</cffunction>
```

here is my JS Function:

```
function getRecs(){
    try{
        location.href = 'myCFMpage.cfm?method=getRecords';
    }catch(err){
        alert('Error')
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure if this even possible, my current code did not trigger alert in `cffunction`. Reason why I'm trying to do this because I have a `cfquery` on this page and I want to grab the data from that query when user click on the button and then to do some manipulation. If anyone can tell me if this is possible or is there any better way to approach this problem please let me know.

Comment: Here is some reference material for you.  https://www.google.ca/#q=cold+fusion+component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past, I've used cfajaxproxy to accomplish calling functions from a component (cfc) to javascript. (I don't do this any more because of different development paradigm, but this might be helpful to get you going.)  First, create a cfc with your functions.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getRecords" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfquery name="someQuery" datasource="someDataSource">
            select * from records
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn serializeJSON(someQuery,'struct')> 
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

In your template, .cfm file, you would use [cfajaxproxy](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-a-b/cfajaxproxy.html) to declare the component for us in your javascript.

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="yourComponent" jsclassname="jsClass">
```

Then, in the same template, in your javascript you would do the following and you will be able to use the cfc functions as methods from the jsClass.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _myFuncs = new jsClass()

    function buttonClicked() {
        var _records = JSON.parse(_myFuncs.getRecords());
    }

</script>
```

Hopefully, this provides some insight.  There are many solutions out there, this being one.  My current development pattern is to use Angular and do $http calls to CF components.  And I roll my own JSON in the cffunctions.  But this is how I started out with just plain JS and CF.

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: If my employer ever lets me leave the office, you got it!